# How can i release an IOS app internally NOT using App Store or Enterprise account?

Tags: ios, app-store

We make apps to solve small business problems like a bookstore(has 5 employees) which needs an app to manage books using a barcode reader, releasing it for Android is easy, but for IOS it nearly impossible in our country!

We have tried these so far:

1. Enterprise account: not available for small business in Iraq(needs DUNS number).
2. Developer account:  needs reinstall every 30 days.
3. Test flight: because it's for testing not releasing, and the customer wants something legit.
4. B2B: isn't available in Iraq.
5. Using US-based enterprises accounts: so expensive and also not Legit.

Comment: "we can't have an enterprise account" Why not? That is the form of account specifically tailored to the problem you want to solve.

Comment: Because creating an enterprise account needs some international registration code which isn’t available in iraq.

Comment: Good answer; perhaps that info should be part of your question. — But I stand by my response. Basically you are asking to do exactly what an enterprise account is for. If you can't use an enterprise account, and you can't release thru the app store (makes sense), then you can't really do what you want to do (in the Apple ecosystem). The TestFlight workaround could work for a while, but it's obviously a misuse of TestFlight.

Comment: Maybe i need to know what Chinese and Russians are doing, I’ve read that they cant register an enterprise either. Thank u dude for the time.

Comment: Are B2B apps available in Iraq?  You can publish your app through App Store Connect but flag it as B2B so it isn't generally available on the App Store and Apple will not reject it for limited applicability.  You can then use Apple Business Manager to download the IPA and Apple Configurator to install it on devices.

Comment: unfortunately, B2B is not available in Iraq, developing ios apps in Iraq is like planning a vacation on Lifetime prison.

Answer (score 1):

There's a possibility to deploy an application through a service like TestFlight, but this needs either a profile installed on the device  or always new build since the old ones expire after 30 days.
Rest you can check the link https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/

Comment: 90 days, not 30.

Comment: If it works for you perfectly then please verify my question as well!

Comment: The enterprise won't work,I am trying to get an enterprise account for 3 months now, we even registered a company in Dubai, but they responded us with this: your organization must be a legal entity to so that it can enter into contracts with Apple. We do not accept DBAs, fictitious businesses, trade names, or branches.